# InDesign: any way to set up document so client can edit content?

Tags: adobe-indesign, tables, formatting, client-relations

I'm creating a brochure for a client which has a table in it. The client will need to change the content in the table in the future.

Is there a way to set up the project so that only the information in the table is changed and the formatting stays the same?

The client has very basic understanding of InDesign.

Comment: Does he need to use InDesign? It seems it would be easier to use Acrobat or set an interactive pdf which can be changes using Reader.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot lock formatting and keep raw data unlocked in InDesign.

Some alternatives:

- InCopy is able to allow limited access to INDD files, assuming your client is willing to learn another software.
- try to set up the table as a linked CSV file. This way the client can edit the CSV in Excel and update the link in InDesign. Some research will be needed here on your side.
- also read [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/82909) question.

Answer (score 2):

Place everything, but the table as page wide images. You can place for example high resolution PDFs with curved texts. If he has Acrobat, he can easily replace one page. That page has the table. You give it as InD file which contains an editable table + the rest as one single image.